# Unable to retrieve the error records with error details from Salesforce using simple-salesforce

Tags: python, simple-salesforce

I am using the simple Salesforce Python library to load data from S3 to Salesforce using Databricks. I am leveraging the bulk API for the data load process. However, when attempting to insert data into Salesforce, if any row violates a Salesforce object constraint (such as having a Null value in a Not Null field), that specific record is not inserted, and the remaining rows are loaded without causing the notebook to fail. Now, I would like to capture these failed records in a separate file, including the error descriptions.

The issue I'm facing is that Salesforce only returns the status, error_message, and ID . There is no direct way to identify the failed rows. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance regarding this matter.

Input Record:
[image]

Write method:
[image]

Output generated
[image]

If there are thousands of records coming in, it becomes difficult to determine which specific rows have failed to load.

Expected Output
[image]

Comment: if you insert let's say 5 records, 3rd one is correct and the rest are invalid so how does the response come is it in sequence? or in a different order? I believe it should be in sequence as you inserted rows.

Comment: I have attempted to insert 5 rows, but the first row has a null violation.  The sequence appears to be correct, but I cannot rely on it. @jaiaswani10

Comment: You can rely on it, if no other option is available. please test with thousands of records. it should work.